Thermopile voltages goes down after I turn on the Gas Fireplace. Glass also fogs with moisture. How do I fix this?
Good morning, I've had trouble keeping my Gas Fireplace lit.
This is a 27 year old Gas Fireplace.  I haven't used it for the past 14 years because I didn't want to bother fixing it.
The Pilot light lights and looks like a good flame hitting the Thermopile.
Thermopile Voltage is 350mv when the pilot light has been lit for a couple minutes.  It fluctuates a bit from 330-360mv.  The pilot light stays on as long as I don't turn on the main flame.
When I turn on my fireplace, the thermopile voltage begins to drop and goes below 200 within a couple minutes.  When the glass is NOT in place and the fake logs are removed, the main flame stays lit.
When the fireplace is all assembled, and I turn on the main flame it notice moisture fogging up the inside of the glass and after a couple minutes, I hear a click and the gas turns off.  The main flame and pilot both immediately go out.
I've cleaned the Thermopile and using a bit of sand paper to clean off any build-up and I made sure that the Pilot flame is strong and directed at the thermopile.
Does anybody have any suggestions as to other things to try?
EDIT:  There are similar posts to this.  The unique thing about this post is that I'm curious as to what causes the almost instant moisture/fog on the inside of my glass when the main flame turns on.
Also, this is a 27 year old fireplace.

This question is similar to: Gas fireplace won't stay lit. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Mine has a thermoPile, not a thermoCouple.  Also, I'm curious as to what causes the moisture/fog buildup on the inside of the glass.  Lastly, this is a 27 year old fireplace, not a new one.

Have you checked to make sure the exhaust vent is not blocked and draws correctly?

Not yet, but I'll give it a look


The unique thing about this post is that I'm curious as to what causes the almost instant moisture/fog on the inside of my glass when the main flame turns on. Also, this is a 27 year old fireplace.

When you combust gas, you get CO2 and water as the main byproducts. The water will be vapour due to the temperature of the flame, but it will readily condense onto cold surfaces - such as the glass. When the glass gets further heated by the flame, the water will evaporate and the glass will be dry during use.
(Chemistry section:
If you burn one part of the simplest alkane, Methane (CH4), you get half a part of CO2 and two parts water (H2O). Alkanes are generally CnH2n+2, and thus produce quite a lot of water. Natural gas is a mixture of different gases, but methane tends to be a very large fraction.
Water and carbon dioxide are the main products, in addition you'll probably get some NOx and some more interesting organic compounds, but that's rounding errors.
)
